# How to use "MsgSrvDoc" in wiki

Tags: ros, documentation, services, wiki, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/maggie_devices_msgs?distro=hydro) for my messages and services but it doesn't work the  "MsgSrvDoc" label when I used in a wiki page.

I based the structure of [my package](https://github.com/UC3MSocialRobots/maggie_devices_msgs) and the wiki page on [common_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/common_msgs) repo.

So, my question is, why is it not working in the wiki page I created?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211081/how-to-use-%22msgsrvdoc%22-in-wiki/) by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-06-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically the `MsgSrvDoc` macro is naive and always try's to go reference the package and .msg from the latest ROS distribution, in this case Jade. Since your package is not released for anything but Hydro, it does not find the file needed to generate the documentation.

The easiest work around for this would be to release your package for Jade (and while you're at it Indigo). This doesn't take very much time and should fix your issue.

However, this is a pretty serious limitation of the macro, I would recommend you open an issue against our roswiki repository:

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues

I won't guarantee that we'll get around to addressing it in the near future, but at least the limitation will be captured and maybe someone else (maybe even yourself) can contribute a better macro.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) on 2015-06-12**:
Thanks for your quick answer @william. I have written the issue on GitHub. It could be fine if at least the macro is compatible with the LTS version of ROS and the last one. Because in this moment, we don't have in mind migrate our code to Jade, if any, we would think to migrate to Indigo.